# Choose whether to automatically add a taxonomy with the same name as the post

Tags: posts, custom-taxonomy, taxonomy, blog

I created a custom taxonomy within the blog post. It's called "FootNotes." I would like there to be a checkmark inside in the creation of the post that asks me "Are there any notes inside this post?" If I choose "yes" it automatically creates within the custom taxonomy this "note" with the same name as the published article. Thank you

Comment: It sounds like you might want to take a look at custom meta boxes which can allow you to create a form that stores metadata about a post. You could probably use them to provide the tick box and trigger the action.

Comment: Hi, sorry for the delay I didn't see the notification. Thanks for the reply could you give me some more tips or examples to study? Thanks